# Trouble determining type of a variable

Tags: rust

I'm trying to solve a simple interview problem in rust. Here's the solution:

```
struct ZigzagIterator {
    iter: std::iter::Peekable<Box<dyn Iterator<Item = i32>>>, // this is wrong.
}

impl ZigzagIterator {
    fn new(v1: Vec<i32>, v2: Vec<i32>) -> Self {
        let v1_iter: std::vec::IntoIter<_>  = v1.into_iter(); 
        let v2_iter: std::vec::IntoIter<_>  = v2.into_iter();
        let iter = v1_iter.zip(v2_iter).flat_map(|(a,b)| vec![a,b].into_iter()).chain(v1_iter).chain(v2_iter);
        Self {
            iter: Box::new(iter).peekable()
        }
        
    }
    
    fn next(&self) -> i32 {
        self.iter.next().unwrap()
    }
    
    fn has_next(&self) -> bool {
        self.iter.peek().is_some()
    }
}
```

The type of ZigZagItertaor.iter is incorrect and I'm having trouble getting this to compile by either adding/removing Box's, or trying to specify the  exact type here. So, the question is two parts.

1. what is the exact type of ZigZagIterator.iter?
2. is there a way I could arrange the code in ZigZagIterator (struct + trait) to make the type more readable? (i.e. using a Box like I tried to do here)

Comment: Can you clarify what this iterator is supposed to do with the two input vectors?

Comment: It's just used to facilitate the next and has_next methods. The function of the entire struct is that it accepts two vectors, allows zipped access first and then sticks the remainder of elements on the end.

Comment: Point of curiosity: is this code you wrote, or is this code presented to you along with some questions?

Comment: It's code I wrote to try and solve a problem w/ rust's iterator api instead of writing out the algorithmic solution.

The function signatures are from leetcode, so I couldn't change those. It seemed like it was relatively straightforward to conceive of a solution that would work but your answer highlighted some of my mistakes in reasoning about how to get it working.

Comment: Both `vec!` and `.into_iter()` are unnecessary in your `.flat_map` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type is correct, but you can't convert a `Peekable<T>` to a `Peekable<U>`, even if `U` is a boxed trait object that can be satisfied by `T`.  Put another way, the compiler doesn't infer that `Box::new(iter)` needs to be converted to a boxed trait object until it's already buried in another type (`Peekable`), at which point the conversion isn't possible.

You can help the compiler figure this out by boxing in a separate assignment with a type annotation:

```
let iter: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = i32>> = Box::new(iter);
Self {
    iter: iter.peekable()
}
```

Alternatively, you can force the conversion by casting the result of `Box::new()` inline:

```
Self {
    iter: (Box::new(iter) as Box<dyn Iterator<Item = i32>>).peekable(),
}
```

However, then you're going to run into the problem that `v1_iter.zip(v2_iter)` moves out of both `v1_iter` and `v2_iter`, so `.chain(v1_iter).chain(v2_iter)` is an error.

One way around this would be to buffer the first part of the sequence in a vector.  Here's an example of that approach:

```
fn new(v1: Vec<i32>, v2: Vec<i32>) -> Self {
    let shortest = std::cmp::min(v1.len(), v2.len());

    let mut v1_iter: std::vec::IntoIter<_> = v1.into_iter();
    let mut v2_iter: std::vec::IntoIter<_> = v2.into_iter();

    let head: Vec<_> = v1_iter
        .by_ref()
        .take(shortest)
        .zip(v2_iter.by_ref().take(shortest))
        .flat_map(|(a, b)| vec![a, b].into_iter())
        .collect();

    let iter = head.into_iter().chain(v1_iter).chain(v2_iter);

    Self {
        iter: (Box::new(iter) as Box<dyn Iterator<Item = i32>>).peekable(),
    }
}
```

- Note we declare the iterators `mut` so that we can use them without moving them.
- To avoid moving them, we call `.by_ref()` which is really just a shorthand for taking a mutable reference to the iterator, but is more ergonomic. `some_iter.by_ref()` winds up being the same exact thing as `(&mut some_iter)`.
- We need to limit the iterators given to `zip()` to the length of the shortest vector, otherwise an item can be skipped when the first vector is longer than the second. (Thanks @kmdreko for pointing that out.)
- We need to collect the zipped elements in a vector, otherwise there would be two lifetime problems:

  - The returned iterator would need to borrow locally-declared `IntoIter` values, but the implied lifetime of the boxed iterator is `'static`.
  - The `.chain()` calls would be impossible because both the `head`
    iterator and the chain iterators would both need a mutable reference to the `IntoIter` values, which violates Rust's aliasing rules.

We can correct these issues a bit and still use the built-in iterator utilities by altering our approach.

We will map the `i32` elements to `Option<i32>` where items are `Some`, and chain each iterator to one producing `None` forever, and zip these together.  This will produce a tuple (`(Option<i32>, Option<i32>)`).  We will stop iterating when both iterators produce `None`.

Then, after flattening we just need to remove the `None`s and unwrap the `Some`s which we can very conveniently do using `filter_map` with the identity function.

Here's what that would look like:

```
fn new(v1: Vec<i32>, v2: Vec<i32>) -> Self {
    let shortest = std::cmp::min(v1.len(), v2.len());

    let v1_iter = v1.into_iter().map(Some).chain(std::iter::repeat(None));
    let v2_iter = v2.into_iter().map(Some).chain(std::iter::repeat(None));

    let iter = v1_iter
        .zip(v2_iter)
        .take_while(|i| *i != (None, None))
        .flat_map(|(a, b)| [a, b].into_iter())
        .filter_map(|i| i);

    Self {
        iter: (Box::new(iter) as Box<dyn Iterator<Item = i32>>).peekable(),
    }
}
```

---

You also have some easily-correctable errors in `next` and `has_next` -- both require mutable access to `self.iter` but they take `&self`.  The simple fix is to change both to take `&mut self`.

```
fn next(&mut self) -> i32 {
    self.iter.next().unwrap()
}

fn has_next(&mut self) -> bool {
    self.iter.peek().is_some()
}
```

---

I'd recommend changing `.flat_map(|(a,b)| vec![a,b].into_iter())` to `.flat_map(|(a,b)| [a,b].into_iter())` which will do the same thing, but doesn't require a heap allocation as there is no resizable vector involved.

Comment: This was really helpful and helped me work through my understanding of rust more. Thank you!

Comment: Just a heads up that using `.zip` is going to be wrong (unless you impose your own checks on it). Since the vectors can be of unequal lengths and `.zip` has to call `.next()` to even see if its at the end and should stop zipping, it will miss one element if the first vector is longer than the second. [playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5d22021e62e85fd5d6a95b768301f395).

Comment: @kmdreko Good catch. For this and efficiency reasons, it's likely OP will want to write their own iterator implementation instead of delegating to the standard iterator utilities.

Comment: Yep, looks like my idea to use the standard iterators for this doesn't make sense in the end. I learned a bit about rust though, which was my longer term goal. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @kmdreko A quick hack fixes that issue. The updated code passes the test in your playground. It's still not as efficient as a manual implementation but it should at least be correct now.

Comment: @kmdreko I found a way to do this using just the standard utilities without buffering. The `chain`s might hurt performance but it's a good exercise anyway, and at least there's not any more `chain`s than the original code.

Comment: @Wren CC you as well, see the above comment and the edit to my answer.

Comment: You don't need the `into_iter()` call either, just `[a, b]` works for `flatten` or `flat_map`